# Scrapy Returns empty list when scraping from yahoo finance

Tags: scrapy

When I use this code on Yahoo Finance it returns an empty list but when used in another site it works fine. And its not an error in the xpath.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from scrapy import Selector

html = requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/SM/key-statistics?p=SM').content

sel = Selector(text=html)

# Naming Sheet
ticker = sel.xpath('//*[@id="quote-header-info"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/h1/text()').getall()
print(ticker)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this way data is generating:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
#from scrapy import Selector

headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36'}  
html = requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/SM/key-statistics?p=SM', headers = headers).content
        
sel = pd.read_html(html)
print(sel)
    
    # Naming Sheet
    # ticker = sel.xpath('//*[@id="quote-header-info"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/h1/text()').get()
    # print(ticker)
```